# How to get the value of a variable from a object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am having the object `config` and when I fetch the `config["RegionId"]`, it will give me `${Region}`. Now I want to fetch the value of `Region`. As I have got ${Region}, I thought I could do `` console.log(`${val}`) `` to get `'abc'`. But it is not working.

How to get this? This is what I have tried,

```
var config = {
    "RegionId" : "${Region}"
}

var Region = 'abc'
var val = config['RegionId']

console.log(`${val}`)
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". You just have an object. JSON is a string format.

Comment: Just remove the quotes around `${Region}` in the object property so that you aren't storing a string, but rather the value of the variable.

Comment: Hi, @ScottMarcus, actually the configs are stored in a json file.

Comment: Fine, but that file holds a JSON "string". There is no such thing as a JSON "object".

Comment: Yes, @ScottMarcus. Let's say {"key" : "value"}. So the value for a key in any config will be string. So do you have any idea how to get the value?

Comment: If you want to convert your JSON string to an object, use `JSON.parse(string)`. I'll update my answer to show this because your question wasn't clear.

Comment: Sure @ScottMarcus. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, you can't store a template literal in a JSON string because they are code and JSON doesn't store code. I'm closing this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put double quotes around the property value. Use back-ticks (for [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) as you are doing for `val`. And make sure you've declared `Region` prior to attempting to access it.

```js
var Region = 'abc';

var config = {
    "RegionId" : `${Region}`
};

var val = config['RegionId'];
console.log(`${val}`);
```

And while your question is centered around template literals, I hope you know that for this scenario, they add no value and are overkill. Here's the same thing with regular strings variables:

```js
var Region = 'abc';

var config = {
    "RegionId" : Region
};

console.log(config['RegionId']);
```

Answer (score -1):

try using **eval** function

```
var config = {
    "RegionId" : "${Region}"
}

var Region = 'abc'
var val = config['RegionId']


console.log(eval("`"+val+"`"));
```

Comment: `eval()` is evil and there are really only VERY VERY RARE use cases when it is needed. Most situations that use `eval()` wind up needing it because the solution was not thought out properly.

Comment: This is working. But is there any standard javascript way to do that? I am asking just for knowledge. And how safe is eval?

Comment: @AbinashBiswal `eval()` is not safe, changes scope, and as my comment above says, should really never be used. This is why `JSON.parse()` was created. It's a safer version of `eval()` for JSON strings, but as I say in my above comment. JSON strings should never contain code, which is what you are doing. You should re-work your thoughts about what you are doing.